# Spring MVC and URL generation to a specific controller

Tags: spring-mvc

Well let me try to explain what I need: once upon a time I have been contracted by a company to work for six months. The company was using an internal MVC framework, which was really outdated and bloated. Anyway I miss one great thing about it. It had JSP tags that you would fill with a controller name (as configured in xml files) and the "Action" (yeah was struts based), so that the resulting URL would be correctly pointing there (and I didn't have to worry about writing it by hand).

I was wondering if there is something similar in Spring MVC? It would be great

Comment: It would be, yes. Sadly, I'm not aware of such a thing. Struts was totally inflexible, but that meant it was easy to generate URLs for it. Spring MVC bends every which way, so there's never a single way of doing anything.

Comment: Guess I'll have to write my own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With spring-mvc - no. But [grails](http://www.grails.org/), which is built ontop of spring-mvc, has this exact functionality:

```
<g:createLink controller="yourController" action="yourAction" />
```